# Is there a way to add alt attributes to ZingChart?

Tags: accessibility, zingchart, section508

For general accessibility and section 508 compliance, we need the ability to add alt attributes to rendered charts.  Even an empty alt would be sufficient.

Comment: An empty alt may satisfy compliance, but it surely won't do much for accessibility. Also, please improve your question by showing example code along with anything you've tried.

Comment: I do not disagree with your statement and the visualization is simply a visual representation of other textual content on the page. I did speak with ZingChart and there is no immediate plan to add an accessibility modules (unless I am willing to pay).  Since other libraries already include this, I will be going elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For outside reference. The ZingChart image map does not contain an alt tag. This has been updated and will be pushed out in the newest release v2.6.1. This release may be about 2-3 weeks from the time this answer was published.

**Note** This problem was easier to solve with direct contact through support@zingchart.com. While we don't want to discourage public outreach, the fastest way to reach us is through support@zingchart.com. It goes directly into our ticketing system.

The (alt=””) will pass the test and tell screen readers it is decorative and not informational.
[image]

Comment: Thank you following up on this and identifying a solution.